# Newtonsoft Json Parser

Tags: c#, json

How I Parse the following result which is coming from https://graph.facebook.com/google/

```
{
   "about": "Organizing the world's information and making it universally accessible and useful.",
   "checkins": 22645,
   "company_overview": "Google is a public and profitable company focused on search services. Named for the mathematical term \"googol,\" Google operates web sites at many international domains, with the most trafficked being www.google.com. Google is widely recognized as the \"world's best search engine\" because it is fast, accurate and easy to use. The company also serves corporate clients, including advertisers, content publishers and site managers with cost-effective advertising and a wide range of revenue generating search services. Google's breakthrough technology and continued innovation serve the company's mission of \"organizing the world's information and making it universally accessible and useful.\"",
   "founded": "1998",
   "is_published": true,
   "location": {
      "street": "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
      "city": "Mountain View",
      "state": "CA",
      "country": "United States",
      "zip": "94043",
      "latitude": 37.421956357856,
      "longitude": -122.08422985089
   },
   "mission": "Google's mission is to organize the world's information and make it universally accessible and useful.",
   "products": "See a full list:\nhttp://www.google.com/options/index.html",
   "talking_about_count": 60684,
   "username": "Google",
   "website": "www.google.com",
   "were_here_count": 0,
   "category": "Website",
   "id": "104958162837",
   "name": "Google",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/Google",
   "likes": 12341682,
   "cover": {
      "cover_id": "10151163547067838",
      "source": "http://sphotos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s720x720/546101_10151163547067838_18950259_n.jpg",
      "offset_y": 0,
      "offset_x": 0
   }
}
```

Comment: @BhushanFirake : Bhushanji mi sangato na, kahi prayatna kela nahiye tyani.

Comment: @Freelancer Lolz...first time on SO a Marathi Comment....:)

Comment: First create class for location, cover and container from above code keep properties names exactly same as it is defined in JSON object

Comment: For more info visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520378/deserialise-nested-json-with-newtonsoft-and-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<outputClassName>(inputObject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating and supporting multiple classes representing json structure, I prefer deserialize json into dynamic object:

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse(json);
//d.founded == "1998"
```

Answer (score 4):

Paste that JSON in http://json2csharp.com that will give you the mapped classes which will be:

```
public class Location
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
}

public class Cover
{
    public string cover_id { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public int offset_y { get; set; }
    public int offset_x { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string about { get; set; }
    public int checkins { get; set; }
    public string company_overview { get; set; }
    public string founded { get; set; }
    public bool is_published { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public string mission { get; set; }
    public string products { get; set; }
    public int talking_about_count { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public int were_here_count { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public int likes { get; set; }
    public Cover cover { get; set; }
}
```

Later you can use Newtonsoft JSON parser as:

```
RootObject myObject =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

You should see the [documentation for Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm)